# Do I need heavy duty Hose Pipe for Immersion Chiller?

Tags: wort-chiller

I am building an immersion chiller (following [this](http://www.berrybrew.co.uk/how-to-build-a-wort-chiller/) tutorial). Looking at hose pipes online I was surprised to find them rated for temperature. Standard garden hose seems to be up to 40C (104F) and 'heavy duty' hose up to ~50C (122F).

All the tutorials I have looked at just mention hose pipe without mentioning anything about temperature rating. The chap in the one I am following just grabbed some from the garden..

I have no idea how hot the water leaving the chiller will actually be beyond 'somewhere between ground water temp and 100C'. I do know that some people like to collect the first few gallons to then use for cleaning as it is hot enough for that. So I am thinking that 50C isn't unrealistic when the wort is still ~100C?

Will the water coming out be hot enough to damage a regular hose pipe?

Comment: I don't feel that going from a 40°C to a 50°C rated hose will change much...  Your water might comme out at 60-70°C, so as Rob mentionned, as long as you don't use that hose to drink water, a little deterioration will not be noticable...

Answer (score 1):

Long ago- I used regular hosing for this similar thing (And assuredly many homebrewers do) and it was ~fine. The hose will degrade a bit over time at those temps- but as long as the water from it wasn't ever getting consumed, it never bothered me. The hose however never just melted flat out when running the chiller, but it did get a bit soft.

The only issue I ran into was if the hose touched a hot part of the kettle or burner and got a hole in it- but that probably a result of too many beers on a brew day.

If you really want something higher rated, you can either get some silicon tubing or get a hot-water tank or washing machine hosing which can handle pretty high temps.